# How do you test filepath.Abs failure in your Golang code?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, go-testing

In my Go code, I have to use filepath.Abs() several times, which may lead to different errors that my method returns.

```golang
func (s *service) myFunc(path string) error {
    dir := s.Component().Dir()
    absDir, err := filepath.Abs(dir)

    if err != nil {
        return my_errors.NewFailedToGetAbsoluteComponentDir()
    }

    absPath, err := filepath.Abs(path)
    if absPath != nil {
        return my_errors.NewFailedToGetAbsPath()
    }

    // more code...
    return nil
}
```

In my unit test, I want to test it, but the only way I can think of is to inject filepath.Abs as a dependency into my struct.

Is there any other way I did not think of?
Or do you think that this kind of test is unnecessary?

Comment: Some things are not worth testing.

Comment: I agree. That's why I was asking. I am always wondering how the TDD guys handle this.

Comment: I'm a "TDD guy", and I would normally not test this, unless the working directory is likely to be unknown in my context (see my update on my answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the source code for the `filepath.Abs` function in the standard library, we can see when it returns an error, and then try to trigger that condition in our tests.  `filepath.Abs` has different implementations depending on which target OS it's compiled for, but the [Unix implementation](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.2:src/path/filepath/path.go;drc=bbf795ebb114918a8e8dc7fd4d825cd5928d3f4d;l=304), for example, looks like this:

```
func unixAbs(path string) (string, error) {
    if IsAbs(path) {
        return Clean(path), nil
    }
    wd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return Join(wd, path), nil
}
```

So the only time it will ever return an error is when `os.Getwd()` returns an error.  An easy way to make `os.Getwd()` return an error is to ensure that your current working directory doesn't exist. This can be done in a test as so:

```golang
    dir, _ := os.MkdirTemp("", "") // Create a temporary directory
    os.Chdir(dir)                  // Change to that directory
    os.RemoveAll(dir)              // Delete that directory
    fmt.Println(os.Getwd())        // This will now return an error
```

Now this has the problem that it changes the working directory for the entire process, which could interfere with other tests.  So it's important to both reset the working directory after this test runs, and also to make sure that no other tests that depend on the working directory run at the same time.

To reset it, put this at the beginning of your test:

```golang
    origWd, _ := os.Getwd()
    t.Cleanup(func() {
        os.Chdir(origWd)
    })
```

And to make sure no other conflicting tests run at the same time, don't call `t.Parallel()` in your test.

---

Is it worth it to test this?  Usually not.  How often is your working directory likely to be invalid?  Under most circumstances, never.  If that describes you, I simply wouldn't test this part of your code.

However, if you're building a CLI tool, for example, where the working directory is in constant flux or often unknown, then such a test may indeed be worth it.

Just make sure your test provides some actual value, before you go to this much effort :)

---

I've made a video discussing this question, and the general question for anyone interested in a longer discussion of the topic:  [Answering StackOverflow: How do you test filepath.Abs in Go?](https://youtu.be/-7Bn3j8gkQo)